# How can I get certain data using Jsoup?

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am websrapping a webpage using Jsoup, but It gives me some info I don't need, Is there a way to use some kind of regex in an element in java?

I get this

> < span id="lblRefSellMsg">¢559.41< /span > (avoid the spaces blank spaces between <>)

And the info I need is

> 559.41

Finally my code looks like this

```
public class dato {

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    String tasa = null;
    Document d = Jsoup.connect("http://indi-eco.appspot.com/tcd").timeout(6000).get();
    Elements ele= d.select("span#lblRefSellMsg");
    System.out.print(ele);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `text()` method on your `Element` or `Elements` object:

```
System.out.print(ele.text());
```